# How does python handle 3D array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a long list of numbers in string and I have to save that to an 3D array. I was able to convert a long list of numbers into 3D array but I found that while layer 0 was all saved as int, layer 2~N was saved as string.

Is it due to the way the python handles array when saving 3D array?

input string is : 0222112222120000

```
L = 4  
H = 2  
W = 2  
layer1 = [[[0 for x in range(W)] for y in range(H)] for z in range(L)]

def cutInput():
    raw = list(input())
    count = 0
    for z in range(L-1,0,-1):
        for y in range(H):
            for x in range(W):
                layer1[z][y][x] = raw[count]
                count += 1

print(type(layer1[0][1][1]))
print(type(layer1[1][1][1]))
```

result

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: "while layer 0 was all saved as int" - layer 0 wasn't saved at all.

Comment: The `input` function returns a string which is never converted to integers, therefore `layer1` contains strings. It has nothing to do with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah thank you for pointing that out. I didn't see that the range was from L-1 to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the range was from L-1 to 0.
In order to save all of the number, the range had to be L-1 to -1